# JavaScript's Object.create method

Tags: javascript, prototype

i have created an object as follows

```
 var lassie = {
 name: 'Lassie',
 breed: 'Collie',
 speak: function () {
 return 'Woof! Woof!'; }
 };
```

I create another object by using Object.create method of javascript as

```
var obj = Object.create(lassie);
```

now when i console **obj** it gives me  a blank object.
But when i console **obj.speak()** it gives me  **'Woof! Woof!'** .

can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `lassie` as first parameter to [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to set `prototype` of `obj` to `lassie`; iterate `lassie` return properties as second parameter

```js
var lassie = {
   name: 'Lassie',
   breed: 'Collie',
   speak: function() {
     return 'Woof! Woof!';
   }
 };

 var obj = Object.create(lassie, (function() {
   var _obj = {};
   for (var prop in lassie) {
     _obj[prop] = {
       value: lassie[prop],
       writable: true,
       enumerable: true,
       configurable: true
     }
   }
   return _obj
 }()));

alert(obj.speak())
```

Comment: Note, you can also pass `null` as first parameter to `Object.create()` and still  pass enuerable properties as second parameter https://jsfiddle.net/u1cvnz1f/

Comment: @AtulAgrawal Depending on expected result could pass original object, `null` or object literal `{}` as first parameter to `Object.create()`

Comment: But for the same work why i need to use Object.create as i can directly achieve the same thing with out that

Comment: My question is obj is now the reference to an empty object then how it prints the properties of lassie

Comment: @AtulAgrawal The first parameter to `Object.create()` set the `prototype` for the created object. When you pass `lassie` , `lassie` is set as `prototype` of `obj`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create _"propertiesObject
Optional. If specified and not undefined, an object whose enumerable own properties (that is, those properties defined upon itself and not enumerable properties along its prototype chain) specify property descriptors to be added to the newly-created object, with the corresponding property names."_

Answer (score 1):

Basically `Object.create` will create an object that would have no own properties. That means the passed object's own properties would be assigned as the prototype properties of the newly created object and that would be returned.

A sample structure of the object returned from `Object.create()`,

```
var obj = {a:10};
var obj1 = Object.create(obj);
console.log(obj1); // {... __proto__ : {a : 10 ...}}
```

If you want to copy the own propties(enumerable) of the passed object to another one object, then you have to can `Object.assign(obj)` as an alternate to passing second parameter as property descriptor properties for `Object.create`

Comment: _"If you want to create an object with same structure as the passed one, then you have to use Object.assign(obj)"_?

Comment: @guest271314 What I meant was, if OP want to copy the own properties of the passed object to a newer one. Then he has to use `assign`. That too enumerable properties.

Comment: `Object.create()` can be used to pass enumerable properties

Comment: @guest271314 But the own properties will be converted as prototype properties if we use `create`. At the same time, `assign` will copy the own properties as the own properties of the returning object.

Comment: Phrase _"you have to use"_ omits other possible solutions?

Comment: You could pass `null` as first parameter to `Object.create()` and still pass enumerable properties as second parameter https://jsfiddle.net/u1cvnz1f/

Comment: @guest271314 I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you give an example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110219/discussion-between-guest271314-and-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy).

Comment: but when i use obj.prototype it gives me undefined

Comment: @AtulAgrawal  Use this `obj.__proto__` or `Object.getPrototype(obj)` to see the prototype.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy How can i get the all the properties and the methods with this particular object as it gives me a blank object when i console it diretcly

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = Object.create(lassie);
```

By doing this you have created a new object which inherits the properties from lassie.

if you do

```
obj.name; //this prints "Lassie" too.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var lassie = {
 name: 'Lassie',
 breed: 'Collie',
 speak: function () {
 return 'Woof! Woof!'; }
 };

var obj = Object.create(lassie);
```

Now your concern is **now when You console obj it gives me a blank object. But when you console `obj.speak()` it gives you 'Woof! Woof!' .**

Actually here **obj** has now all the properties of **lassie** ,but these are not the **obj** own properties.

Here you will see all the properties of obj:

```
for(var a in obj){
     console.log(a);
     }
```

Here you will see obj's own property:

```
for(var b in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(b)) {    
         console.log(b);
    }
 }
```

This is actually because when we use `var target = Object.create(obj);`
then all the properties are added to target as a prototype properties.

Comment: but why obj.prototype is empty

Comment: You have to use obj.__proto_  to access prototype properties.